# problem on one-to-many relationships entity framework 4.1 mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

i have these models:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Books> FavoriteBooks { get; set; }
}

public class Books
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author{ get; set; }
}
```

When i run DBContext and check the generated tables, the Books table have created Student_Id column. I want the Books table to be just a reference and not linked back to Student.
How can I make this relationship uni-directional and will have no Student_Id column created in Books? can i use fluent-api? or in simple data annotations only?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the fluent API it should look something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasMany(s => s.FavoriteBooks)
                .WithMany();
}
```

That'll create a "StudentBooks" table for you to maintain the many-to-many relationship. It's not a one-to-many relationship as your question suggests, since a student can have many favourite books, but each book might be a favourite of many students.

**Update**

For the sake of completeness, here's how you'd do it if you already have that linking table defined and need to tell EF what the mapping looks like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasMany(s => s.FavoriteBooks)
                .WithMany();
                .Map(cfg => cfg.MapLeftKey("Student_Id")
                               .MapRightKey("Books_Id")
                               .ToTable("StudentBooks"));
}
```

Comment: yes.. will try this maybe this is the one. i tried so many fluentapi's but no result. thanks matt

Comment: any links for complete fluent api subject will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Hi Matt, I've tried your solution, still EF created StudentBooks table (a reference table with StudentID and BookID on it).. Oh now I see, EF had to make a "reference" table (values of BooksId of Students) for it to have a reference. And there's no other way around, please correct if I'm wrong. thanks

Comment: @subseven Yes, without the linking table the relationship you're describing would be impossible.